# Rewrite HAR content via BrowserMobProxy and Selenium

Tags: json, http, har, browsermob-proxy

Is it possible to change the har (with json in it) response from an https site? I see the initial json by `getText()`, then use `setText()`, and change its size by `setSize` and `setBodySize`. The content is changed as I see in debug. But it seems that there is no effect and chrome receives the same old json. Is there a way?

```
    public static class ResponseModifier implements ResponseInterceptor {

    @Override
    public void process(BrowserMobHttpResponse response, Har har) {

        String contentType = response.getHeader("Content-Type");

        if (contentType!=null && contentType.startsWith("application/json")){
            response.getEntry().getResponse().getContent().setText(respond);
            response.getEntry().getResponse().getContent().setSize(respond.length());
            response.getEntry().getResponse().setBodySize(respond.length());
            response.getRawResponse().removeHeaders("Content-Length");
            response.getRawResponse().addHeader("Content-Length", ""+respond.length());
        }
    }
```

I think maybe the point is that `response.getRawResponse().getEntity().getContentLength()` somehow has the old value, but I can't rewrite it. Or is the cause different?

Comment: You're not rewriting a HAR, but a HTTP response. A HAR is an exported archive of JSON descriptions of requests + responses. Am a bit confused why you would request one via HTTP (and then try to fiddle the response) rather than programatically from the proxy server.

Comment: I need to change the http response with json in it, so i thought har is the way. How can I change response content other way?

Comment: `ResponseInterceptor` is the right way, I think the terminology is confusing though - also the API seems to be in flux. Hang on, this is you? https://github.com/lightbody/browsermob-proxy/issues/382

Comment: Not sure I can help much more. I stopped developing with BMP and was waiting to hear that 2.1 was out and the API situation was fully resolved. You can probably answer this question better yourself now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turn out to be far easier than I thought.
I have to use core-littleproxy version of BMP, BrowserMobProxy class and create an instance of BrowserMobProxyServer. The I just use filter:

```
 proxy.addResponseFilter((response, contents, messageInfo) -> {
        if ((contents.getContentType().startsWith("application/json"))) {
            contents.setTextContents(respond);
        }
    });
```

Thanks for reading :)